# Sorting individually calculated results from mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql

Currently for a football league, standings are calculated with their own table so I have to manually input/edit Wins, losses, ties, PF and PA.  I want to generate this dynamically based on the results of the schedule table which is where scores are recorded.

So I have the following ugly code:

```
    $teamidsql = mysql_query("select team_id, count(team_id) as numteams from team WHERE league_id=$currentleague AND team_div='$div'");
$teamid = mysql_result($teamidsql,0,"team_id");
$numteams = mysql_result($teamidsql,0,"numteams");
$endteams = $teamid+$numteams;  
while($teamid < $endteams)
{
$result2=mysql_query("select team_name, team_div,
count(case when (schedule_team1_id = $teamid and schedule_team1_score > schedule_team2_score) or (schedule_team2_id = $teamid and schedule_team2_score > schedule_team1_score) then 1 else NULL end) as wins,
count(case when (schedule_team1_id = $teamid and schedule_team1_score < schedule_team2_score) or (schedule_team2_id = $teamid and schedule_team2_score < schedule_team1_score) then 1 else NULL end) as losses,
count(case when schedule_team1_score = schedule_team2_score then 1 else NULL end) as ties,
sum(case when schedule_team1_id = $teamid then schedule_team1_score else schedule_team2_score end) as pf,
sum(case when schedule_team1_id <> $teamid then schedule_team1_score else schedule_team2_score end) as pa
from schedule, team
where team_id = $teamid AND team.team_div='$div' AND schedule_week >= 1 and schedule_week <= 13 and schedule.league_id = $currentleague and (schedule_team1_id = $teamid or schedule_team2_id = $teamid)") or die(mysql_error()); 

    $t_n = mysql_result($result2,0,"team_name");
    $t_w = mysql_result($result2,0,"wins");
    $t_l = mysql_result($result2,0,"losses");
    $t_t = mysql_result($result2,0,"ties");
    $t_pf = mysql_result($result2,0,"pf");
    $t_pa = mysql_result($result2,0,"pa"); 

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$t_n</td><td>$t_w</td><td>$t_l</td><td>$t_t</td><td>$t_pf</td><td>$t_pa</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    $teamid++;
}
```

Which currently generates the following html:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBVfM.png

My question is how can I sort it?  The old table was easy, but I have no idea how I would take this individual data I'm calculating and then sort it via wins, losses, ties, pf then pa.

Comment: **Heads up!**  PHP is going to be *removing* the `mysql_` family of functions in a future version. Please move to [PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli) if you can!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

datatables is the fastest solution to this problem.  Give the table a class, call datatabes in the onload, and it will render javascript sorting based on the contents of the html.

http://datatables.net/